# Вывод сообщения при переходе с определенной страницы

Tags: php, javascript, html

У меня есть страница с формой обратной связи и отдельный php-файл, реализующий ее функционал. Я сделал автоматический переход со страницы со скриптом на страницу формы после отправки. Как теперь реализовать вывод какого-либо сообщения на странице с формой?

Comment: уточните что за сообщение, в какой момент и где должно выводиться?

Comment: @AlexeyLemesh Пользователь заполняет форму, нажимает кнопку отправки, идет переход на страницу с php-файлом, он отрабатывает и возвращает пользователя назад на страницу с формой. И в этот момент нужно на текущей странице написать что-то вроде "сообщение отправлено"

Comment: может имеет смысл сделать обработку и вывод формы по одному адресу и никакие редиректы не нужны будут.

Comment: @AlexeyLemesh А как это сделать? Засунуть php код в `action=""`

Comment: через сессию после редиректа

Comment: @SergeEsmanovich А поподробнее можно?

Comment: Когда на контроллер кидаешь форму пишешь сообщение через метод для работы с сессией, выводишь сообщение и удаляешь его из сессии после редиректа из контроллера на вьюху

Comment: `после редиректа из контроллера на вьюху` вы где такое видели? @SergeEsmanovich

Comment: @Naumov http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/sessions.html

Comment: @SergeEsmanovich я про редирект с контролера на вьюху. Так как MVC (Модель, Вивер, Контроллер) работает следующим образом человек человек запросил контролер `/about/`  и перешол на контроллер `about` экшин `index` после чего action обрабатывает его запрос и запускает рендер представления, а представление берёт данные из Модели(любое хранилище данных). Как вас может редиректнуть на вивер?

Comment: @Naumov имел ввиду контроллер который отрендерит вьюху, но думаю тут и так понятно не станет же кто то делать редирект на twig файл =)

Comment: @SergeEsmanovich да я уже понял )) просто человек поймёт не так и потом будет уверен что ему надо именно вивер запросить ))

Comment: @SergeEsmanovich why not :D да по сути в некоторых фреймворках есть абстракция блоки  реализующие API между приложением и шаблонами.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
start_session();

if(!isset($_SESSION['message'])) {
    $_SESSION['message'] = null;
}
// ваш обработчик формы
$_SESSION['message'] = "Ваше сообщение";
header('Location:form.php'); // редирект на форму гипотетический
```

далее в form.php

```
start_session();
if(isset(!is_null($_SESSION['message'])) {
    echo $_SESSION['message'];
    $_SESSION['message'] = null;
}
```

где `start_session()` и `$_SESSION['message'] = null` в начале скрипта обработчика

**не забудьте про кодировку файла без BOM – Serge Esmanovich**

Comment: не забудьте про кодировку файла без BOM

Answer (score -3):

```
if($_POST['sendbutton']) {
    include('processing.php'); // тут обрабатываем и проверяем форму, если что-то не так записываем например в переменнту $form_incorect = true;
}

include('form.php');
```

form.php:

```
<form>
<?php if($form_incorect): ?>
Сообщение об ошибке
<?php endif; ?>
<!-- поля формы -->
<input type="submit" name="sendbutton">Отправить</input>
</form>
```

Comment: плохо, достаточно нажать F5 чтобы понять почему

Comment: Зачем нажимать F5 ?

Comment: Зачем писать такой плохой пример? Ещё и советовать обрабатывать форму во вьюхе

Comment: @SergeEsmanovich, для понимания принципа реализации. Лучше конечно отправлять данные на проверку ajax'ом, но человеку сначала нужно усвоить азы...  Принцип базовый, он не может быть плохим. А вот сессии для таких задач, по моему извращение ...

Comment: @SergeEsmanovich, почему вы решили, что он использует MVC патерн?

Comment: serge прав так как достаточно нажать f5 что бы получить сообщение заново

Comment: @Naumov, зачем пользователю при заполнении формы нажимать f5?