# Как сделать уведомление о успешной записи?

Tags: php

Регистрирую пользователя. В `action` перекидывает на страницу `addUser.php`. И потом делаю `header('Location: index.php');` на первую страницу.

Как мне написать сообщение о том, что данные записались успешно. В `addUser.php` нельзя так как там `header` `Location` ошибку выдает. Может как то в сессию записывает если данные записались, то на странице `index.php` выводить сообщение или не так.

Comment: Можно сделать так: в файле `addUser.php` добавить код: `$_SESSION['success'] = 'Успешно создан';`. А потом в **html** добавить код: `<?php echo $_SESSION['success']; unset($_SESSION['success']); ?>`

Comment: Возможен дубликат [вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/497435/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Вывод сообщения при переходе с определенной страницы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/497435/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d1%81-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b)

Answer (score 3):

Если быстро и без сложностей, передай `GET` параметр `success`, если 1, то ок, иначе ошибка, а в `index.php` делаешь проверку на наличие данного параметра со значением 1.

```
header('Location: index.php?success=1');
```